# Callback pattern for handling everything in the body of a function

Tags: javascript, callback

What is the correct pattern to use when my function contains something which issues a new thread/worker inside it's body? To better illustrate the problem please take a look at the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dx29q/

```
function write(text){
    var obj = document.getElementById('foo');
    obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + text + ' ';
}

function test(a,b,callback){

    write(a+b); //A
    setTimeout(function(){write(a-b);},1000); //B    
    write(a*b); //C

    callback(); //D
}

test(3,2,function(){

    write("Finished!");
});
```

The problem is that the actual order in which the actions are performed is ACDB. I would like to execute the callback only after everything in the function before the callback has finished. I have to use pure JavaScript (not even libraries). I'm struggling to find any good tutorials addressing advanced situations when using callbacks, only complete basics.

Thanks for any advice!

*Edits below:*

- the order I need to achieve is (ABC)D, where I don't care about order among ABC as long as D gets executed only after they have completely finished.
- setTimeout is just an example, to better imagine the situations picture a function which calls foo(), bar(), baz() and callback(). Foo, bar and baz need to be executed at the same time separately and callback() has to be called afterwards.

Comment: What's the execution order you're aiming for? ACBD?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ABCD, or to be more precise I don't care about order among ABC as long as D get executed only after them.

Comment: How's that going to work with the timeout then?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I would like to know that as well :) There has to be a way to determine if its safe to fire away the callback function.

Comment: Without rebuilding something like [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) your only real option is to have a structure where you constantly pass around alot of *onComplete*-callbacks. Especially if the executed function themself contain async code.

Answer (score 2):

You should perform extra check, i.e. like below:

```
function write(text){
    var obj = document.getElementById('foo');
    obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + text + ' ';
}

function test(a,b,callback){
    var finished = false,
        interval;

    write(a+b);
    setTimeout(function(){write(a-b); finished = true;},1000);    
    write(a*b);

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (finished) {
            callback();
            clearInterval(interval)}
    }, 100);
}

test(3,2,function(){

    write("Finished!");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U9K5g/1/

Also, it could be useful to you to read about Promises/A+

Great example is - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but it feels kind of dirty, when you create an interval each time you need to wait for something. But I'm probably going to go with this if nobody comes up with a better pattern. Thanks so far ;)

Comment: Yes, it's tricky solution. Advice you to read about Promises - it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an execution order of ABCD. Not sure why you'd want to do it this way though...

```
function test(a, b, callback) {
    write(a+b); //A
    setTimeout(function() {
        write(a-b); //B
        write(a*b); //C
        callback(); //D
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this doesn't check if the functions finished. In the code you posted you just don't call anything until the timeout gets executed. The problem is that this is just an example - imagine a situation where you have functions foo(), bar(), baz() inside and you have to execute them at the same time. This is why I'm asking about a pattern to fix this, not "how to fix my code". This doesn't answer my problem, +1 though, it may help a lot of users.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case I'd have to second @DmitryVolokh's suggestions: either maintain state in a variable and temporarily check on it, or use Promises if you can.